# Logrotate olddir with date

Tags: debian, logging, logrotate

it's possible to configure `logrotate` to create an `olddir` per day?

I'd like to get the same `bash` result, like this:

```
user@blade1022m:~$ date "+%y%m%d"
120208
```

In **/etc/logrotate.conf** (pseudo-code):

```
/home/mhd-01/logs/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 62
  olddir /home/mhd-01/logs/archive/${`date "+%y%m%d"`}/
  postrotate
     /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without hacking `logrotate`.

However, you can 'cheat' and achieve the same effect using a **symlink** and **cron**. In your `logrotate.conf` set `olddir` to `/home/mhd-01/logs/olddir/` and create a daily cronjob that does:

```
mkdir /home/mhd-01/logs/archive/$(date "+%y%m%d")
ln -sf /home/mhd-01/logs/archive/$(date "+%y%m%d") /home/mhd-01/logs/olddir/
```

Make sure this new cronjob runs before the logrotate job - either stick it in `/etc/cron.daily/` with a number in the front (eg. `01_linkrotate`) or set it to run at midnight (00:00)

---

A cruder variant of this solution, without symlinks, would use `cron` to move the contents of `olddir` to the archive. The cronjob, running after logrotate or at the end of the day (23:59), would do the following:

```
mkdir /home/mhd-01/logs/archive/$(date "+%y%m%d")
mv /home/mhd-01/logs/olddir/* /home/mhd-01/logs/archive/$(date "+%y%m%d")/
```

Comment: It might make more sent to create the symlink from a `prerotate` block. No separate cronjob needed....